# VB.net 2008 Deleting a row from Data Grid View "hides" the row before it?

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview, data is from a database. I have a button to delete a row and the database entry, when i click on the button it deletes the correct entry but hides the row above it(but doesn't delete it, which is a good thing)

here's the weird part, the button can be pressed by pressing F4 on the keyboard, when I use F4 it doesn't hide the row above it.

Here's the keydown part:

```
ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
        BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(BindingNavigatorDeleteItem, AcceptButton)
```

And my code when clicking delete

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click

Dim strSql As String
    Dim cmdSql As New OracleCommand
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgview.CurrentRow
    Dim a As String

    If dgview.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("There are no items to remove.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Message")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    a = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Message")
    If a = vbYes Then
        strSql = "Delete from table where ID='" & row.Cells("ID").Value & "'"
        With cmdSql
            .Connection = oracon
            .CommandText = strSql
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            oraread = .ExecuteReader()
            oraread.Close()
        End With
        txtcode.Text = vbNullString
        txtname.Text = vbNullString
        txttelno.Text = vbNullString
        txtadd.Text = vbNullString
        GroupBox1.Enabled = False
        cmdsave.Enabled = False
        cmdcancel.Enabled = False
        dgview.Rows.Remove(row)
        Me.dgview.Refresh()

    ElseIf vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: How is the grid populated in the first place?  From what I can see, I'm guessing that you have populated a `DataTable`, bound that to a `BindingSource` and then bound that to the grid.  If that's true then there's a much better way to delete the row.

Comment: @jmcilhinney you're right that's how the dgv is populated, how should I delete it then?

Answer (score 0):

If you have populated a `DataGridView` by binding it to a `BindingSource` that is, in turn, bound to a `DataTable` then you delete a record by calling either `RemoveCurrent` to delete the current row or `RemoveAt` to delete by index on the `BindingSource`.  That will call the `Delete` method of the underlying `DataRow`, setting its `RowState` to `Deleted` and removing it from the grid.

You then call `Update` on a data adapter to save that and any other pending changes back to the database.  That might be the same data adapter that you called `Fill` on to populate the `DataTable` in the first place or it may not be.